# Append dataframe column to bottom of another column

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my dataframe I have the source "Data", and via some calculations have calculated "Path", stored in another column of the dataframe similar to the example shown below.

```
Date         Data         Path
01/01/2020   101          106
02/01/2020   102          107
03/01/2020   103          108
04/01/2020   104          109
05/01/2020   105          110
```

My aim is to plot a line graph showing the time series "Data" joined at the end by its calculated future "Path" in one chart. To do this, I thought to append "Path" to the bottom of the "Data" column, however have been unable to do figure out how to do this.

```
df['Data'].append(df['path'])
df.tail()
```

Results in just showing the original dataframe. As does:

```
x = []

for i in range(1, len(df)):
    x.append(df['path'])


x = pd.Series(x)
df['Data'].append(x)

df.tail()
```

Would anyone please be able to offer any assistance on the best method to append the "Data" column in order to achieve the plot?

Comment: `df['Data'].append(df['Path'])` works for me. What's your `pandas` version?

Comment: I just upgraded to 0.25.3. Strange - mine still shows the same dataframe as before I appended. The bottom row's index was 897 and it still is for me.

Comment: If you want the index to be  reseted `df['Data'].append(df['Path'], ignore_index=True)`. Else, the index is kept.

Comment: I was just using the index as a reference for the number of rows in column "Data" to show that the length wasn't increasing, i.e. "Path" is not joining onto the end of "Data" for me unfortunately, but thank you for that tip too.

Comment: what' do you get from `df['Data'].append(df['Path'].shape` ?

Comment: **df['Data'].append(df['path']).shape** gives me (1794,), which sounds like the correct number of rows, yet when I type df.head() it only shows me to 897

Comment: It's because it's working. The index from your second column is kept if you don't add `ignore_index=True` as I stated so it'll go from 0 to 897 then to 0,1,...897. Indexes are a way to identify rows, not a count of them.